# AWS EC2 and Tomcat startup.sh

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I installed Tomcat8 on my EC2 instance used following command:

```
sudo yum install tomcat8
```

I want to update `startup.sh` file but I can't find it.
`/bin` folder looks like showed on image:

[image]

How can I update `startup.sh` or reinstall tomcat with `startup.sh` and `shutdown.sh` files in bin folder? I don't have `apt-get` only `yum`

Comment: Do `service tomcat8 start` and `service tomcat8 stop` work?

Comment: @DusanBajic, yes, it works

Comment: @jww, this question can be useful for java developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to review the list of the files installed from the `tomcat8` package, you can run

```
$ repoquery --list 'tomcat8'
```

You'll see that there's no `startup.sh` file, there are many blog and doc posts that will go through the installation, if you want better control on your installed tomcat and want to use the `startup/shutdown` script, it will be better to run a manual installation.

## Manual installation

It's detailed [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/apache-tomcat-8-installation-on-linux) for example

Create a user called "tomcat" to own the Tomcat installation.

```
# useradd tomcat
```

Install the JDK from the tarball under the tomcat user.

```
# su - tomcat
$ tar xzf /tmp/jdk-8u77-linux-x64.gz
```

Install Tomcat from the tarball under the home directory of the "tomcat" user.

```
$ tar xzf /tmp/apache-tomcat-8.0.32.tar.gz
```

Set the following environment variables and append them to the `/home/tomcat/.bash_profile` so they are set for subsequent logins.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_77
export CATALINA_HOME=/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.32
export CATALINA_BASE=$CATALINA_HOME
```

Start and stop Tomcat using the following scripts.

```
$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
```

The Tomcat logs are written to the `$CATALINA_HOME/logs/` directory by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try at `/usr/libexec/tomcat/server` on AWS Linux 2